# Problems simulating MOSFET astable multivibrator circuit

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am currently trying to simulate an astable multivibrator circuit to drive the MOSFET in a boost converter. I am using MOSFETs instead of BJTs for the multivibrator circuit.

However, my simulation does not seem to work. The output voltage of both the gates of the NMOS are at a constant 1 V. I have attached the picture of my schematic.

[image: This is the schematic from pspice.]

This is where I got the schematic from [here](http://virtual.cvut.cz/dyn/examples/examples/electronic/mosmulti/).

Comment: Are you sure the MOSFETs are the right way around? Those are some terrible models

Comment: @DerStrom8 yes they should be I just used the 'mirror horizontally' to get the MOSFET on the left. And yeah I have to use those particular models for this.

Comment: I mean are they mirrored vertically (i.e. the source is where the drain should be, and vice versa)?

Comment: @DerStrom8 I meant I mirrored horizontally sorry. So the source is still at the bottom and the drain is at the top.

Comment: I understood what you were saying, but I don't understand how you know where the source and drain are. It's very poorly labeled

Comment: @DerStrom8 Well before mirroring the source is the bottom pin and the drain is the top (I know this because I've had to work with this model before) so after mirroring horizontally it would still be the same. Anyway, I'm still not sure why it's not working. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: My instinctive thought is that it has to do with the initial conditions. Maybe it needs a bit of a "kick" to get it oscillating?

Comment: Those are not valid MOSFET symbols.  There is nothing to indicate which end is the source.  Also, there is no indication of the channel polarity.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know the parameters of your MOSFETs, I can't tell whether your bias network is designed to oscillate.  If it is OK, then here are some ideas:

Often when an oscillator circuit won't begin to oscillate in simulation, it's because a real-world oscillator needs some noise to get it going.  This is more often the case with positive-feedback amplifier circuits.

In other cases oscillation won't start with perfectly-matched component values used by the simulator.  Real component tolerances give enough asymmetry in the initial conditions to start oscillation.

Some simulators allow you to place an initial charge on capacitors which will offset the initial condition enough that oscillation starts in the absence of noise.  In CircuitLab, you can place a timed-opening switch so a capacitor is pre-charged in the initial condition and allowed to discharge normally during running.  I found that some JFET-based astable multivibrator circuits need this in real life, not just in simulation.  (See the one here for example: [FET PRINCIPLES AND CIRCUITS — PART 2](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/fet_principles_and_circuits_part_2))

It's also important in CircuitLab to simulate with "Skip initial: Yes" so that any asymmetry in the circuit has a chance to prevent convergence to a steady state.

Below is a modified version of your circuit, built to work with the 2N7000 MOSFET model built into CircuitLab.  It is also modified so that it will start oscillating without any prompting:

- Voltage dividers at the gates are set to turn on the transistors.
- There's a slight asymmetry in the drain resistors to encourage oscillation.
- It's set so that when one transistor turns on, the increase in current causes just enough voltage drop on the drain resistor to switch off the other transistor.

This example also runs at a much lower frequency than yours would.  Follow the link below the schematic to run the simulation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Vi1m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I added a comment above, then noticed that this thread died over 4 years ago.

Comment: @AnalogKid I never consider threads dead.  They turn up so often in web searches, someone is bound to ask the same question in the future.  I happened to come across this CircuitLab trick recently so I added it.  But yes, those are weird symbols.  They look like depletion-mode to me.  I'm not sure which software that schematic came from.

Comment: There are a number of design reasons why an oscillator won't oscillate. Since this thread seems to be about oscillator startup, here are two general suggestions for that:

1. For a non-production circuit, you can pin out any nodes. Add one or more current sources with single pulse to disturb the circuit from its non-oscillatory state. Infinite off resistance, and easily tuned for ramp rate, amplitude, and pulse width.

2. For a production IC, add dummy devices on state nodes. Force one or more using reset (if available) or power supply.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler trick is to add *some* asymmetry to the circuit -- some small (1 %) difference between normally equal resistors etc., and then ramp up the V1 supply from 0 V. That will kick the circuit.